# Why is my RegExp always evaluating to false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript

Sorry, if this turns out to be a duplicate, but I can't seem to find the right solution for this. I've never really had to dig into regular expressions before, so my question might be rather trivial.

I have the following javascript function:

```js
validateFilename(filename: string, config: any) {
    const validationRule = new RegExp(config.rules[0].pattern);
    const isMatch = validationRule.test(filename);
    return isMatch;
}
```

My rules look like this:

```json
{
  rules: [
    { pattern: '^Bildschirmfoto', name: "screenshot image" },
    ...
  ]
}
```

My regular expression is `/^Bildschirmfoto/` and I want to match any filename starting with the string "Bildschirmfoto". It always evaluates to false.

The data I am iterating over looks like this:

```
"Bildschirmfoto 2023-07-09 um 15.12.18.png"
"Bildschirmfoto 2023-07-09 um 15.12.37.png"
"Bildschirmfoto 2023-07-09 um 16.43.13.png"
"Bildschirmfoto 2023-07-09 um 17.09.25.png"
"Bildschirmfoto 2023-07-12 um 21.57.37.png"
```

But when I change `filename` in `validationRule.test()` to `"Bildschirmfoto"`, I evaluates to true.

What am I not seeing here? The filename is just a string, i checked with typeof.

I already found out I should remove the global flag at the end as this flag could cause problems like mine, but even without the flag, it always evaluates to false.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `/^Bildschirmfoto/.test('Bildschirmfotohello')` is true. Please make sure the code is a [mcve] showing the issue. Right now we cannot see how you are using the function nor it's output

Comment: What is the value of `filename` when the result is `false`? It should be something that *doesn't* match the regex.

Comment: @e I know it's true. But why is it not evaluating to true is I pass a variable containing the same string? That is my question

Comment: It will return true only if filename start with `Bildschirmfotohello` . Here is the demo : https://jsfiddle.net/51dp9aog/1/. Can you please tell the format of filename.

Comment: @McMuellermilch Please update the code so we can find out why

Comment: Did you check if the char codes match what you expect them to be?

Comment: `/^Bildschirmfoto/.test("Bildschirmfoto 2023-07-09 um 15.12.18.png")` is also true?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I updated my question with some example filenames. 

As I said, I've tried replacing the filename with the same exact string it would contain and it evaluates to true. Just when the string comes in through the filename, it evaluates to false

Comment: Taking everything you've said at face value, it seems that the filename might contain characters that differ from those you expect in the regexp despite looking the same. [For instance](https://gist.github.com/StevenACoffman/a5f6f682d94e38ed804182dc2693ed4b)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out my problem. As per the last comment (thank you, @spender), my filename turned out to contain a soft-hyphen which caused the test to fail:

```
--> Filename: Bildschirmfoto 2023-07-09 um 15.12.18.png
66  | 66  | B
105 | 105 | i
108 | 108 | l
100 | 100 | d
115 | 115 | s
99  | 99  | c
104 | 104 | h
105 | 105 | i
114 | 114 | r
109 | 109 | m
173 | 102 |    <-- Problem!!
102 | 111 | f
111 | 116 | o
116 | 111 | t
111 | 32  | o
32  | 50  |
50  | 48  | 2
48  | 50  | 0
50  | 51  | 2
51  | 45  | 3
45  | 48  | -
48  | 55  | 0
55  | 45  | 7
45  | 48  | -
48  | 57  | 0
57  | 32  | 9
32  | 117 |
117 | 109 | u
109 | 32  | m
32  | 49  |
49  | 53  | 1
53  | 46  | 5
46  | 49  | .
49  | 50  | 1
50  | 46  | 2
46  | 49  | .
49  | 56  | 1
56  | 46  | 8
46  | 112 | .
112 | 110 | p
110 | 103 | n
103 | NaN | g
```

I received my filename from fs in node with a soft-hyphen in it. Removing the symbol with unicode 173 solved that immediate problem. Not too sure if blindly removing the soft-hyphen every time will cause any sideeffects though. My goal is to have an array with user defined regular expressions that can handle any given filename or string.

The updated version of my function looks like this:

```js
validateFilename(filename: string, config: any) {
    const normalizedFilename = filename.normalize("NFC").replace(/\u00AD/g, "");
    const validationRule = new RegExp(
      config.rules[0].pattern.normalize("NFC").replace(/\u00AD/g, "")
    );
    const isMatch = validationRule.test(normalizedFilename);
    return isMatch;
  }
```